# Some exam question on power series convergence

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I provide my solution to the problem and wonder if I was thinking in a correct way.

**Find the radius of convergence of** $$\sum_{n=0}{1 \over 1+n3^n}z^n$$ **and give with reasoning a point $z_0$ on the edge of the disc at which the series converges.**

Here's how I hustle this problem:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\rho=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|{(1+(n+1)3^{n+1} \over (1+n3^n)} \right| = 
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|{1+(n+1)3^{n+1} \over (1+n3^n)} \right|\\
= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|{1+n3^{n+1}+3^{n+1} \over 1+n3^n} \right|\\
= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|{{1 \over 3^n}+3n+3 \over {1 \over 3^n}+n} \right|\\
=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|3+ \frac3n \right|\\
= 3 
\end{eqnarray}
\\ \text{The series converges, when }|z|<3 \text{ or } -3 < z < 3
$$

Thus we know that the series converges for all $z \in \, ]-3,3 \,[$.

Let's hope one of the edge points $\{3,-3,3i,-3i\}$ will satisfy the convergence condition (in case none of them suits, we need to evaluate something more complicated in form of $x+iy$). Using ratio test we check 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{for }  z_0 = 3:\qquad \rho =\lim_{n \to \infty}{3^n \lbrack 1+(n+1)3^{n+1}\rbrack\over 3^{n+1}(1+n3^n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{1+(n+1)3^{n+1}\over3+n3^{n+1}}\\
=\lim_{n \to \infty}{n+1\over n}=1
\end{eqnarray}
$$
As $|z_0|=3>\rho=1$, the series diverges at this point. 
$$
\text{for } z_0 = -3: \qquad \rho =\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|{(-3)^n \lbrack 1+(n+1)3^{n+1}\rbrack\over (-3)^{n+1}(1+n3^n)}\right|= 1
$$
As $|z_0|=3>\rho=1$, the series diverges at this point.

However having made this step I decided to make sure I am doing well and use *Mathematica* to find out if the series really doesn't converge at $-3$ and $3$. *Mathematica* told me, that it doesn't converge at $3$, however it **does** at $-3$, which contradicts my calculations.

```
SumConvergence[((-3)^ n)/(1 + 3^n*n), n]
True
```

Where have I mistaken?

Comment: At limit of ratios $1$ the Ratio Test is **inconclusive**. So applying it is useless, on the boundary you need a different argument.

Comment: If $z \in \mathbb{C}$  then  $\; |z|=3 \;\Leftrightarrow \; z=3e^{i\theta},\;\; 0 \leqslant \theta < 2\pi.$

Comment: @AndréNicolas is it true for power series convergence test using the radius of convergence? Because what I do is I find $\rho$ and then if $z>\rho$ the series diverges and vice versa. I just calculate the radius according to the definition of it and then compare it to $z$. In my case I get $\rho = 1$, which is absolutely legal, again, according to the definition ($\rho \ge 0$).

Comment: If $|z|\gt \rho$, we have divergence. If $|z|\lt \rho$, we have (absolute) convergence. For $|z|=\rho$, we could have convergence or divergence. And the behaviour may be different for different $z$ on the boundary of the disk of convergence. The Ratio Test, or Root Test, by its nature, can give no information about $z$ such that $|z|=\rho$. Different tools are needed, as illustrated by the answer that has been given.

Comment: @AndréNicolas if I want to find $\rho$ I can **always** find it as $$\rho = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left| {a_n \over a_{n+1}} \right|$$
cannot I? And it will be always $\ge 0$ so, why not $1$?

Comment: Well, if that limit exists, yes. Sometimes the limit doesn't exist, but Root Test gives you $\rho$. But the issue is not finding $\rho$, you had done that. The issue is what happens when $|z|=\rho$. For such $z$, we need other tools.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so for edge values root and ratio tests are never applicable, do you mean that?

Comment: Yes, I do mean that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $z=-3$ you can use simply Leibniz criterion: you have convergence of the series since $\frac{3^n}{1+n3^n}$ converges to zero.

For $z=3$ the simplest way is the comparison test: $\frac{3^n}{1+n3^n}\geq\frac{1}{1+n}$. Since the harmonic series diverges also your series does.

Comment: That's absolutely true, however could you explain why I cannot use the comparison of the value with the radius of convergence?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems you are trying to compute the convergence radius for the series with $z_0$ fixed, but it does not make sense, since the convergence radius is defined for power series, in which there is a "variable". Once you fix $z_0=3$ your power series becomes a series with non-negative terms. For that "constant series" you can apply the ratio test (the computation is the same as for the radius but the meaning is different) and that test gives you some information only if the number you obtain is different from 1.

Comment: I got your point fully!